# How to make Bootstrap JS Collapse Bold after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I need to make Bootstrap JS Collapse Bold after clicking on it.

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo8" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td>
                <div class="faq_title bold" id="q13">How do I renew? </div>

                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo8">

                    <div class="col-md-8 text-justify py-4 pl-0" style="border-top: 1px solid #DEE2E6;">
                        <p>
                            Some TXT
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Use class `font-weight-bold` like `<div class="faq_title bold font-weight-bold" id="q13">How do I renew? </div>`

Comment: But I need after expand

Comment: @STA is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Collapse Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#events) to make the active title bold. I hope the following example will help you.

```js
$('.collapse').on({
  'show.bs.collapse': toggleCollapseBold,
  'hidden.bs.collapse': toggleCollapseBold
});

function toggleCollapseBold(e) {
  $(e.target).prev().toggleClass('font-weight-bold');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo8" class="accordion-toggle">
    <td>
      <div class="faq_title bold" id="q13">How do I renew? </div>
      <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo8">
        <div class="col-md-8 text-justify py-4 pl-0" style="border-top: 1px solid #DEE2E6;">
          <p>
            Some TXT
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```